# Vegetable internal temperature (oven)

Tags: vegetables, oven

This question is inspired by this week's cooking of a 3kg (estimate - it was plenty huge and took 6 people to eat) courgette / zucchini. The 'quote' is a digression about what happened - skip it if you will).

> I had created two 'boats' to stuff:
>   the 'hull' was about 2 cm thick.
>
> My guesstimate at how long it should
>   cook was 30 minutes at 160C, and then
>   check.
>
> In the end I used about 20 minutes at
>   160, 10 minutes at 180, and 10 minutes
>   at oven full blast (~260). You can
>   probably tell it wasn't cooking fast enough and I just wanted to pump in heat at some point.
>
> I started with visual inspection to
>   see whether it was cooking well: at
>   some point I decided to stick my
>   digital probe in the 'hull'. The
>   temperature was 82C when I pulled it
>   out of the oven: this produced a good
>   result.

My question: can you determine how well a vegetable is cooked (in the oven) through this type of probe use, and what temperature should a vegetable reach (a table would be ideal, but any answer's welcome).

Comment: I have a difficult time imagining that a perfect chart could be created, as everyone seems to have a preferred definition of "done" for each vegetable and even per cooking technique.  For example, my done on most vegetables is crispier than a lot of people prefer.

Comment: I think your intuition about how soft it should feel when you poke it, thermometer or not, is probably pretty good; "until barely firm" is a much easier and safer directive for zucchini than for meat. But I'm still curious!

Comment: @justkt - rare, medium, well done vegetables? If there can be a accepted range for steak....

Comment: hm...that could work...interesting idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical sous vide temperature for most vegetables is right around 82-83 C, so I think you nailed it. Of course it is much more difficult to reach a consistent temperature in the oven than sous vide, but the texture at a given temperature should be roughly equivalent.

Comment: +1 Awesome. I'm going to see if any other answers come up, but that's a great match. Is there a sous vide veg temp list anywhere?